# Connect to MYSQL Databases hosted in a virtual machina from Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I trying to conncet to my MySQL Database hosted in a virtual machine, but it doesn't work 
for me.

Here is my setup:

- Newest Ubuntu Server witch Apache2 mysql installed and is working
- Database "feedback" with the table "test" set up and filled with test data
- The network adapter is bridged. The IP of the server is (if I type in ifconfig) 10.0.0.1 and the IP of my pc is 10.0.0.4.
- Port 3306 was manually opened. The jar mysql connector java 5.1.21-bin.jar is a Referenced Libary

Here is the Java Code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        System.out.println("Sucess");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.1/feedback","root","myrootpassword");

        con.setReadOnly(true);



    } catch (Exception e) {


        System.err.print("NO CONNECTION");
    }

  }
}
```

I hope that someone could help with this, because I'm working on this problem for a while.

Thanks

Comment: Ignore the System.out.println("Success");

Comment: why do you think that you not connected?

Comment: because it's in try/catch block; without it it wouldn't work anyway, because the methods reqire one

Comment: if you see `NO CONNECTION` in output, then add `e.printStackTrace()` and add trace to question

Comment: because the connection con = driverManger.getConnection... breaks the try block(=>there is an error) I have tried to give this expression a own try/catch block. This line is definitly the reason

Comment: Then please define "it doesn't work". What symptoms do you see? Can you please dump the contents of the exception in the `catch` block so we can see what it is?

Comment: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)...

Comment: "*The IP of the server is (if I type in ifconfig) 10.0.0.1*" is this mysql server

Comment: can you connect to mysql from another client(gui or console - no matter) from host in which you run java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just two ideas:

- Is MySQL configured to listen on all addresses and not only local ones ? What's the value of the bind-address configuration directive ? 0.0.0.0 means "listen on all interfaces", while 127.0.0.1 means "listen on the localhost interface, for access from this host only".
- Maybe you can extract some details about the issue in your catch statement ?

Hope this helps !

Comment: Please give me a hint how to configure the mysql server that it listens on all interfaces here the exception ouptput: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)

Comment: I still don't know if it is the problem, but to make it listens correclty, please edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf, and make sure there is no line `skip-networking` (or it is commented with a dash character in front) and that there's a (not commented) `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` line. If you make any edit, please restart mysql with `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`.

Comment: There is this section: "Instead of skip networking the default is now to listen only on localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure". Bind- adress 127.0.0.1. Should I change this to 0.0.0.0? If only this change, it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, as long as you have `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` it will not accept connections from external machines (here the non-virtualized one). This is mandatory, but maybe not sufficient. Also don't forget to restart mysql after any configuration change.

Comment: I thought root has all permission but I was wrong. Thanks ; guy you are great :)

Comment: The root user has all permissions once it's talking to mysql, but this "filtering" appears at the OS level, before your connection actually reach the MySQL server. Is it working now ? if so, please accept the answer ! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If i am correctly understand a question ,To connect VM database,then check for the following steps

1.jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.1/feedback.

2.Make sure there is no firewall blocking the access to port 3306.

3.make sure the user you are connecting with is allowed to connect from this particular hostname.

Comment: Do I have to give permission if I log in as root?

Comment: Be sure to GRANT appropriate permissions to that host and user in your MySQL schema even if you are login as a root.

Comment: I thought root has all permission but I was wrong. Thanks guys you are great :)